# Does Convert.ChangeType call ToString() internally?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

Is there any difference between:

`value.ToString()`

and

`(string)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(string))`

Comment: As a future reference, download dotPeek. http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It calls the `IConvertable.ToString` after ensuring the types are `IConvertable`.

```
case TypeCode.String:
   return (object) convertible.ToString(provider);
```

So as a result, its doing a lot more work just to call `ToString` with an `IFormatProvider`. It will all depend on the implementation of the type that implements `IConvertable`.

The `provider` comes from `(IFormatProvider) Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

This is what `int` does.

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return Number.FormatInt32(this, (string) null, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}

public string ToString(string format)
{
  return Number.FormatInt32(this, format, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}

public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
{
  return Number.FormatInt32(this, (string) null, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}

public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)
{
  return Number.FormatInt32(this, format, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when target type is string, Convert.ChangeType works like this:

```
if (value == null)
{
    return null;
}

var convertible = value as IConvertible;
if (convertible == null)
{
    throw new InvalidCastException();
}

return convertible.ToString();
```

so it's quite different from value.ToString();